# How to run gitlab-runner job locally that requires artifacts

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a pipeline with many jobs and the last job failed. I'm trying to debug the issue, but the job requires artifacts from previous jobs.

How can I run this job locally with `gitlab-runner` so it has access to these artifacts?

Comment: This is scheduled for our `12.6` release. Please upvote the [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2797) and add any comments you feel missing from the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible (yet).
See the limitations of the `exec` compared to regular `CI` [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/README.html#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec) (*artifacts -> not available*).
Consider upvoting the [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2797) to get this fixed.